# Is it possible to set chunk defaults only for a specific engine?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using SQL blocks in an RMarkdown document, and I want the `echo` option to default to `FALSE` for all of them – but only for `sql` blocks, not others.
I know I can set `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)`, but that would set it for all chunks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Yihui suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534569/is-it-possible-to-set-chunk-defaults-only-for-a-specific-engine#comment110596412_62535177), the proper way to do this is to use an [option hook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/option-hooks.html). The following sets `echo=FALSE` for `sql` chunks and `echo=TRUE` otherwise:

```
knitr::opts_hooks$set(echo = function(options) {
  options$echo <- options$engine != "sql"
  return(options)
})
```

I'll leave my original answer below … for entertainment. It's a workaround, required in a hypothetical parallel universe without option hooks.

---

You can query the current engine via `opts_current$get("engine")`. Based on this, you can use the following function (and extend it however you like) to determine the desired value for `echo`:

```
conditionalDefaut_echo <- function() {
  return(opts_current$get("engine") != "sql")
}
```

The challenge is to evaluate this function whenever parsing a new chunk. This can be achieved with `quote`:

```
opts_chunk$set(echo = quote(conditionalDefaut_echo()))
```

To be honest, I am not sure how reliable this is – this kind of [metaprogramming](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html) depends on the internal workings of knitr and might break in the future. (Maybe Yihui wants to comment on this …)

---

A full example with engines `r` and `asis`, where `echo` is `FALSE` for `asis` chunks and `TRUE` otherwise:

````
```{r}
library(knitr)

conditionalDefaut_echo <- function() {
  return(opts_current$get("engine") != "asis")
}

opts_chunk$set(echo = quote(conditionalDefaut_echo()))
```

```{asis}
I'm invisible.
```

```{r}
print(1) # code visible
```
````

Comment: I'll leave an exercise to you to use an option hook to modify `echo` when `engine == 'sql'`: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/option-hooks.html :)

Comment: @YihuiXie Oh dear, I completely forgot about option hooks. I'll update my answer with a banner pointing to option hooks ...

Comment: Awesome. I'm using something similar to load the body from an external file when it's empty (https://gist.github.com/f920f09e97de8ad1cd849d3977aa40dd), but when it's *entirely* empty, the hook doesn't get called. If I have a single empty line, it does. Ideas on why this is?

Comment: @retorquere I'm not sure. Maybe chunk options of empty chunks are not evaluated (and option hooks don't get executed). This would make a lot of sense - why evaluate options that will apply to ... nothing? Just guessing - if you really need this, I recommend asking a new question.