# Is there a way to detect the chunk language when setting knitr chunk options?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, quarto

Summary - is there any way for the code run when setting knitr chunk options to know the language of the contained chunk?

Detail:

I have a knitr (in fact Quarto) book in which I have both R and Python chunks, where the Python chunks run via Reticulate.

In fact the R chunks are for an R edition of the book, and the Python chunks for a Python edition.

I'd like to tell knitr to `eval=FALSE, echo=FALSE` for the R chunks, when building the Python edition, and vice versa for the Python edition.

Is there a way for me to detect the chunk language at chunk option evaluation time, in order to do something like this?

````
# My document

```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
is_py_ed <- TRUE  # Worked out elsewhere.
is_r_ed <- FALSE  # Worked out elsewhere. 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  eval=(this_is_python_chunk & is_py_ed) | (this_is_r_chunk & is_r_ed),
  echo=(this_is_python_chunk & is_py_ed) | (this_is_r_chunk & is_r_ed)
)
```

```{python}
# This chunk gets dropped in R edition, kept in Python edition.
```

```{r}
# This chunk gets dropped in Python edition, kept in R edition.
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an [option hook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/option-hooks.html) and get the current language engine used by knitr to eval and execute the code of the current code chunk using `options$engine` (where `options` is a list of chunk options passed to the hook functions).

````
---
title: "Chunk language"
format: html
---

# My document

```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
is_py_ed <- TRUE  # Worked out elsewhere.
is_r_ed <- FALSE  # Worked out elsewhere.

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = "", eval = "")

knitr::opts_hooks$set(
  echo = function(options) {
    if(!is.logical(options$echo)) {
      options$echo <- (options$engine == "python" & is_py_ed) | (options$engine == "R" & is_r_ed) 
    }
    return(options)
  },
  eval = function(options) {
    if(!is.logical(options$eval)) {
      options$eval <- (options$engine == "python" & is_py_ed) | (options$engine == "R" & is_r_ed)
    }
    return(options)
  }
)

```

```{python}
print("Hello from python")
```

```{r}
print("Hello from R")
```

```{r, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE}
print("Hello from R (evaluated in python edition)")
```
````

---

Note: As a workaround to enable overriding the chunk option `echo` and `eval` locally, I have set them to empty strings globally. Then the option hooks will change the values accordingly if they are not set in the chunk header.

---

[image: code chunk execution based on chunk language]

Comment: Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62534569/10858321) for another informative answer.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful.  And -how would I override the `eval` and `echo` on a chunk-by-chunk basis?  It looks like this sets the values unconditionally.

Comment: I am confused the phrase "chunk-by-chunk basis" :(. Can you explain what do you mean this? :)

Comment: I mean add another chunk - say in the Python edition, with {r, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE}, where I force that chunk to get evaluated, despite the opts_hooks default, which would otherwise set `echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE`.

Comment: @MatthewBrett, Oh, Now I get it! I have updated the answer. Check that out!